# Python Cleanco Type Error when using Lamba

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, typeerror

None of the other TypeErrors seem to be helping with this. How do I solve this type error for running a cleanco lambda expression?

```
df.PARTY_NAME_UPPER = df.PARTY_NAME_UPPER.apply(lambda x: cleanco(x).clean_name() if type(x)==str else x)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-3d6fb1759b1d> in <module>
----> 1 df.PARTY_NAME_UPPER = df.PARTY_NAME_UPPER.apply(lambda x: cleanco(x).clean_name() if type(x)==str else x)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4198             else:
   4199                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4200                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4201 
   4202         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-14-3d6fb1759b1d> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 df.PARTY_NAME_UPPER = df.PARTY_NAME_UPPER.apply(lambda x: cleanco(x).clean_name() if type(x)==str else x)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: I do not see a `clean_name()` method in cleanco package: https://github.com/psolin/cleanco - what does this function supposed to do?

Comment: I was following this direction. https://medium.com/@isma3il/supplier-names-normalization-part1-66c91bb29fc3

Comment: clean_name() =  Remove business entities extensions (1)